# How can i add an extension to Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I am using the following command in Powershell

```
 az webapp config ssl show
```

But i get an error:

```
 az : az webapp config ssl: 'show' is not in the 'az webapp config ssl' command group.
```

How can i add the extension ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `az extension add --name` cmdlet to add a particular extension in Azure CLI as shown below

[image]

Here is the az extension add cmdlet with the allowed properities:

```
az extension add [--name]
                 [--pip-extra-index-urls]
                 [--pip-proxy]
                 [--source]
                 [--system]
                 [--upgrade]
                 [--version]
                 [--yes]
```

Refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/extension?view=azure-cli-latest) for more information about `az extension` cmdlet with supported operations.

Comment: So if i do the following: az webapp config ssl -h  , I dont see the show Command. All that is available is the bind, create, delete, import, list, unbind and import.  How can i get the  "show" command in that list , what do i need to type in the PS console ?

Comment: @Tracey I have tested in my local environment and it is running with the latest version of AzCLI V 2.42.0 and i am able to see the show operation under `az webapp config ssl -h` cmdlets as shown in [this image](https://i.imgur.com/10NCEd0.png). I would recommend you to install the latest version of AzCLI in your local and test it out.

Comment: my azure-cli version is 2.7.0. I just checked and that seems to be released way back in 2020. So can i update to the latest ?

Comment: I have tried to upgrade using az upgrade and gives error az: 'upgrade' is not in the 'az' command group.

Comment: @Tracey can you try upgrading to latest version by downloading the MSI from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: @Tracey - Glad to know that your problem has resolved